# How can I close a TabBar Controller from inside the Controller?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBar Controller with dynamically added tabs. Adding the tabs is easy - I simply get the `[self viewControllers]` array, add a new View Controller, and use `[self setViewControllers]` to update the TabBar. Now, I'd like to be able to press a button in one of the added View Controllers to remove it from the TabBar.

What can I compare from `self` in an added View Controller to the `[[self tabBarController] viewControllers]` array, to find a match to remove?

I can't use the Tab's title, as there may be duplicates. I tried comparing `self` to the items, but it's actually `[self parentViewController]` in the array. I can't use `parentViewController` as when the View is opened in the "More" menu, the `parentViewController` is the "More" View Controller. I don't know of any way to access information, including `tag`, in the View's immediate parent.

Any hints would be great, and thanks in advance!

As an example, here's my current code. It works, but not when the tab is in the "More" menu. This is run when a button in a View Controller in a TabBar is pressed:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[self tabBarController] viewControllers]];
for (int i = 0; i < [temp count]; i++)
{
    UIViewController *test = [temp objectAtIndex:i];
    if (test == [self parentViewController])
    {
        [temp removeObject:test];
        break;
    }
}
[[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:temp];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, now I feel a bit stupid. I was sure I had tried this before, and other answers urged not to do this, but...

I can use `[[self tabBarController] selectedIndex]` to get the position in the array of the currently selected tab, then remove the object at the position. It's what I was looking for - quick and efficient, without requiring much extra code.

It works exactly as expected. When the items are reordered by the user, the array is reordered as well; so while the initial index changes, the index when the user presses the Close button is the index of the Controller in the array.

Well, I got it in the end...